# Iterative bubblesort

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I was doing some exercises in c++, on the topic of sorting algorithms, and I couldn't understand one of them.

It said to implement a function that, given an array of integers, should order them using the bubblesort algorithm (iterative), that should terminate as soon as a **for** cycle didn't promote an exchange of elements. Is this even possible?

The way I understand it, a normal condition for terminating the algorithm would be to have the sorting be equal to one. So, in this example,

```
void bubblesort( int v[], int size ) {
    for( int i = size; i > 0; --i )
        for( int j = 0; j < i; ++j ) {
            if( v[j] <= v[j+1] ) continue;
            int aux = v[j];
            v[j] = v[j+1];
            v[j+1] = aux;
         }
}
```

But this doesn't solve the exercise, does it?

Comment: Yes it is possible, and it is also on Wikipedia with pseudo code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Implementation

Comment: Not only this doens't solve the exercise, but it's also undefined behavior and a bug, because the shown code is off by 1, and runs off the end of the array.

Comment: if v is one array that start from 0 the last element is size-1 and not size... so your array start from 1 to size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I get of your question, you need to terminate the sorting once the inner for loop does not carry out any exchange. This can be done with the help of a `bool`, as follows:

```
void bubblesort(int v[], int size)
{
    bool flag;

    for (int i = size; i > 0; --i)
    {
        flag = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            if (v[j] <= v[j + 1]) continue;

            flag = false;

            int aux = v[j];
            v[j] = v[j + 1];
            v[j + 1] = aux;
        }

        if (flag) break;
    }
}
```

Explanation: If the inner `if` condition is not satisfied, then the value of `flag` is changed. If for every iteration the `if` is satisfied, then the value of `flag` does not change, which is checked at the end of outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

No, given the description your solution doesn't solve the task.
Yes it is possible.
The following code contains all changes you would need to fix it.

```
void bubblesort( int v[], int size ) {  
    boolean change; //create a boolean to track if the current iteration changed anything 
    for( int i = size-1; i >= 0; --i ){  
        change = false; //at the start of each iteration set it to false
        for( int j = 0; j < i; ++j ) {  
            if( v[j] <= v[j+1] ) continue;  
            change = true; // if something changed set it to true  
            int aux = v[j];  
            v[j] = v[j+1];  
            v[j+1] = aux;  
        }  
        if(!change){ // when it's still false at the end of the itteration you are done
            return;
        }
    }
}
```